# Parsing html with simple_html_dom.php

Tags: php, html, xml

I am trying to parse some html using simple_html_dom.php

in the html there is the following

```
 <th colspan="6">Saturday 14 April 2012 <span class="blahclass" title="blatitle"></span></th>
```

I want to get the inner text of the th element, ie "Saturday 1 March 2012"

I thought this would work

```
$date = $html->find('th[colspan=6]');
```

and then later in a loop to get the string:

```
$thedate = $date[$c]->innertext;
```

However the script doesnt complete it stops at this point.

*update*

this is the error

Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/prem/snatchandinsertresults.php on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/prem/snatchandinsertresults.php on line 17

it happens at this line

```
$thedate = $date[$c]->innertext;
```

Comment: [This replication of your code](http://codepad.org/oJyw21jV) works, so the problem is probably not in the code you provided. Please provide more context, and make sure your [error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) settings are correct (it's possible you're getting a fatal error somewhere in the script but PHP is not showing it because of a disabled `display_errors` for example).

Comment: The Log says it crashes at this line $thedate = $date[$c]->innertext;  Notice: Undefined offset: 21 in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/prem/snatchandinsertresults.php on line 17

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/prem/snatchandinsertresults.php on line 17

Comment: if i set $date to "" it works so the rest of the script is fine its very shorty

Comment: The most obvious cause would be that your loop is doing more iterations than it should be doing. If that's not the case you'll need to provide more code (and more importantly, reproducible code).

Comment: I stripped out all code and just tried this after instantiating the simple_html_dom object with my html: $data = $html->find('th[colspan=6]');
 echo count($bruno);

Comment: 00000000000000000000 <---- this was the response for count()

Comment: Could you edit your question with a piece of complete code that demonstrates the problem (see [SSCCE principles](http://sscce.org/)), it's hard to tell what's going wrong with just these little snippets.